# State Machine In Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, state, state-machine

Does anyone have an example of a simple state machine that can be implemented in Swift? I've been googling around, but have only seen a lot of third party libraries which are pretty opaque to me. I've also seen a lot of high level discussions where people *talk* about state machines, but haven't shown any code. Is it possible for someone to do a simple counter example (like add 1 / subtract 1)? Or point me to one? I know it's a big ask, but my google-fu is failing me. Thank you.

Comment: Look for a sample project made by Apple, Inc. through Xcode documentation.

Comment: well they have things like this: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/GameplayKit_Guide/StateMachine.html, but i want to know how to make a state machine from scratch, not use a predefined one.

Comment: I suggest you learn how to use Xcode to look for sample projects.

Comment: @PeterWeyand What kind of state machine are you looking for, exactly? It's a very broad term that can entail a whole range of solution approaches

Answer (score 2):

Apple's `GamePlayKit` already has state machine implementation as `GKStateMachine`. But `GamePlayKit` is available only from iOS 9 so I had to clone `GKStateMachine` (and `GKState`) to support iOS 8 in one of my apps. Hope it will be helpful.

**EHStateMachine.swift**

```
import Foundation


class EHStateMachine {
    private(set) var currentState: EHState?
    private let states = NSMapTable<AnyObject, EHState>(keyOptions: [.objectPointerPersonality],
                                                        valueOptions: [.strongMemory])

    // MARK:

    init(states: [EHState]) {
        guard states.count > 0 else {
            fatalError("Can't create state machine with zero states.")
        }

        let tempStates = NSHashTable<AnyObject>(options: [.objectPointerPersonality])

        for state in states {
            guard !tempStates.contains(type(of: state)) else {
                fatalError("Duplicate instances of \(type(of: state)) found.")
            }

            tempStates.add(type(of: state))
        }

        for state in states {
            state.stateMachine = self
            self.states.setObject(state, forKey: type(of: state))
        }
    }

    // MARK:

    func canEnterState(_ stateClass: AnyClass) -> Bool {
        if (states.object(forKey: stateClass) == nil) {
            return false
        }

        if currentState == nil {
            return true
        }

        return currentState!.isValidNextState(stateClass)
    }

    func enter(_ stateClass: AnyClass) -> Bool {
        if !canEnterState(stateClass) {
            return false
        }

        let previousState = currentState
        let nextState = states.object(forKey: stateClass)

        previousState?.willExit(to: nextState!)
        currentState = nextState
        currentState!.didEnter(from: previousState)

        return true
    }

    func update(deltaTime seconds: TimeInterval) {
        currentState?.update(deltaTime: seconds)
    }

    func state<T: EHState>(forClass stateClass: T.Type) -> T? {
        return states.object(forKey: stateClass) as? T
    }
}
```

**EHState.swift**

```
import Foundation


class EHState {

    weak var stateMachine: EHStateMachine?

    // MARK:

    func isValidNextState(_ stateClass: AnyClass) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func didEnter(from previousState: EHState?) {

    }

    func willExit(to nextState: EHState) {

    }

    func update(deltaTime seconds: TimeInterval) {

    }
}
```

If you target iOS 9 you should probably use `GKStateMachine` and `GKState` instead of these.